# How to implement generic return type property on .net for dynamic type data-binding?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, types, properties

I am trying to listing my parameter list on DataGrid in WPF. I am using data-binding feature for that DataGrid. Some columns of the grid are combo boxes and all cells of that are editable by user. But, I want to change some combo box's items source according to selection of the user on the previous combo boxes.

I have tried object return type for the properties of the combo boxes using. The data was changed I wish but the changed cell is not like combo box anymore, it is like textbox. I wrote that code below. I have changed type object on the grid and I need to change the `changeableEnum` object too. And I want to see other items on the `changeableEnum` combo box in the cell.

```
// Parameter type is enum that I've defined
private ParameterType type = ParameterType.Input;
private object changeableEnum;

public ParameterType Type {
    get { return type; }

    set {
        type = value;
        if(type == ParameterType.Input) {
            // Input type is enum that I've defined
            ChangeableEnum = new InputType();
        } else if(type == ParameterType.Output) {
            // Output type is enum that I've defined
            ChangeableEnum = new OutputType();
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("Type");
    }
}

public object ChangeableEnum { 
    get { return changeableEnum; } 
    set { changeableEnum = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ChangeableEnum"); }  
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what your goal is. What do you expect this `ChangeableEnum` to do? Do you want to have a property which can store two different types of enums? Also, you generally don't use `new` when using `enum`. You should use `OutputType.YourEnumValue` if you want to set a specific value to that property.

Comment: I am sorry, the issue might not be clear. Yes, Exactly I want to have a property which can store two different type of enums. Also, I know the new keyword is not coorect for declare enum here. I've tried you said before. That part was remained when I wrote the question here because  I've tried a lot of things for solving that.

Comment: I see. I think the issue is that the data grid doesn't interpret the value as enum anymore since it's now of type `object`. I don't know this control in detail but I believe that there is no way to do this with a single property. One workaround I have in mind is that you manually add the columns and switch over your `ParameterType` to decide what type the column should have. This column will not allow other values and would have to be exchanged if you want to switch what enum will be used. Maybe someone else has a better idea :)